# Why doesn't svn merge do anything?

Tags: svn

I am trying to understand in detail how `svn merge` works.

I have a file `test` committed in two revisions:

in revision 230553, it has one character `/` (and the newline)

in revision 235554, it has one character `$`:

```
svn diff -r 230553:230554 test
Index: test
===================================================================
--- test        (revision 230553)
+++ test        (revision 230554)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-/
+$
```

The current local version, is changed back to `/`. Now, I expect that if do this:

```
svn merge test@230553 test@230554
```

the local copy will change to `$`. But no, nothing happens, the command succeeds, does not complain, but the file `test` is not even touched.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: This question is more suited to this site, as it does not involve writing code, so that's why I posted here.  But in desperation, I also posted on SO, and there, somebody suggested the option `--ignore-ancestry` and that seemed to work.